# Проверка расширения файла перед сохранением

Tags: c#

Качаю файл с удаленного хоста. Сайт `content/type` отдаёт `application/octet stream`. Можно ли предварительно узнать какой файл скачивается? По урл невозможно определить

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url+"download");
 req.Method = "GET";
 var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
 Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: По bin сигнатуре файла можно попробовать, но это не обязательно будет небольшой со всеми файлами, только с известными сигнатура по в вашей базе. Например в Urlmon.dll есть функция с именем FindMimeFromData.

Comment: `По урл невозможно определить` - по url достоверность файла определить нельзя никогда :) внутри файла может быть что угодно, например вирус сразу после заголовка :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

Вы можете например использовать функцию `FindMimeFromData()` живущую в `Urlmon.dll`.

Вот один из пeримеров как ее подключить в C# :

```
public static string getMimeFromFile(string file)
{
    IntPtr mimeout;
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
    throw new FileNotFoundException(file + " not found");

    int MaxContent = (int)new FileInfo(file).Length;
    if (MaxContent > 4096) MaxContent = 4096;
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file);


    byte[] buf = new byte[MaxContent];        
    fs.Read(buf, 0, MaxContent);
    fs.Close();
    int result = FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero, file, buf, MaxContent, null, 0, out mimeout, 0);

    if (result != 0)
    throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(result);
    string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeout);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeout);
    return mime;
}
```

Подробнее на http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/findmimefromdata.html

**Вариант 2:**

Использовать что-то готовое для этих целей, например https://github.com/Muraad/Mime-Detective

**Вариант 3:**

Написать парсер самому, с учётом сигнатуры заголовков различных файлов, например, как часть, определения типов сигнатур наиболее распространенных файлов:

```
public class MyMimeType
{
    private static readonly byte[] BMP = { 66, 77 };
    private static readonly byte[] DOC = { 208, 207, 17, 224, 161, 177, 26, 225 };
    private static readonly byte[] EXE_DLL = { 77, 90 };
    private static readonly byte[] GIF = { 71, 73, 70, 56 };
    private static readonly byte[] ICO = { 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] JPG = { 255, 216, 255 };
    private static readonly byte[] MP3 = { 255, 251, 48 };
    private static readonly byte[] OGG = { 79, 103, 103, 83, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] PDF = { 37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46 };
    private static readonly byte[] PNG = { 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82 };
    private static readonly byte[] RAR = { 82, 97, 114, 33, 26, 7, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] SWF = { 70, 87, 83 };
    private static readonly byte[] TIFF = { 73, 73, 42, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] TORRENT = { 100, 56, 58, 97, 110, 110, 111, 117, 110, 99, 101 };
    private static readonly byte[] TTF = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] WAV_AVI = { 82, 73, 70, 70 };
    private static readonly byte[] WMV_WMA = { 48, 38, 178, 117, 142, 102, 207, 17, 166, 217, 0, 170, 0, 98, 206, 108 };
    private static readonly byte[] ZIP_DOCX = { 80, 75, 3, 4 };
```

---

Ну и самое интересное, как получить часть файла, для анализа типа файла одним из приведенных выше способом. Надо получать файл не полностью, а отправляя заголовок `Range` в http запросе, подробнее об этой технологии тут https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Вот пример кода как это организовать на `C#`:

```
int size = 256;

using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(0, size);

    var response =  await httpclient.GetAsync(url,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[size];
        var bytesread = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```